# Xcode 7, Swift 2.0, Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, carthage

After upgrading to `Xcode 7.0`, I convert all project to `Swift 2.0`. But I can't update `Carthage` libraries. I get this warning:

> Failed to load plugin at: /Users/Alexandr/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CocoaPodUI.xcplugin, skipping.
>   Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]

And several errors:

> Box/Box.swift:6:37: error: 'Printable' has been renamed to
>   'CustomStringConvertible' /Box/Box.swift:31:10: error: 'toString' has
>   been renamed to 'String' Box/MutableBox.swift:8:51: error: 'Printable'
>   has been renamed to 'CustomStringConvertible'
>   Box/MutableBox.swift:25:10: error: 'toString' has been renamed to
>   'String'

How can I use `Swift 2.0` version of frameworks? My carthage file looks like:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" 
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" 
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa"
```

Add "swift 2.0" in the end of framwork didn't work.

```
~ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.0
Build version 7A220
~ carthage version
0.9.1
```

### Edit:

Seams `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON` already supports `Swift 2.0`. For `ReactiveCocoa` we need add branch "swift2".

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "swift2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all what Cartage version do you have?
run the command

```
Carthage version
```

The latest stable i think is 0.8.0 and I suggest you to upgrade it if you have an older version.
To do so run

```
brew upgrade carthage
```

After that check that all libraries you are using supports `Swift 2.0`, if not check different branches from master, maybe they did not merge them yet.

I just saw you run 0.9.1, maybe it has problem? I'm using 0.8.0 and works fine with Alamofire

Comment: I downgrade Carthage to 0.8 but problem still appear. Found that `ReactiveCocoa` have another branch with `Swift 2.0` support.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me by putting the following in my Cartfile:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" >= 4.0
```

Currently v4.x of ReactiveCocoa is in alpha but v3.x does not support Swift 2